# Passing parameters to Action method

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I have few filter options in a form. I have given action method as the action. Code is something like below.

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm
       (new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "accountsGrid" }))
       { %>
<body style="overflow: scroll">
 <%= Html.TextBox("subAccNumber",accId) %>
 <%= Html.TextBox("accountName", Name)%>
 <%= Html.TextBox("address", address)%>
    <%} %>

<%Html.RenderAction("SelectAccounts"); %>

</body>

public PartialViewResult SelectAccounts(string accId,string accountName,string address)
        {
             // Do some stuff
                     return PartialView();
}
```

Can i crete a dictionary or something of all the input parameters(form controls) and pass to action method directly? Or I have to add seperate parameter for each control?

Comment: You should accept some previous question's answer to get a good response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Create a view model (recommended approach):

   ```
   public class AccountViewModel
   {
       public string SubAccNumber { get; set; }
       public string AccountName { get; set; }
       public string Address { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   and have your controller action accept this view model as argument:

   ```
   public PartialViewResult SelectAccounts(AccountViewModel account) { ... }
   ```
2. Your current implementation where parameters are passed as action arguments
3. Fetch parameters from request:

   ```
   public ActionResult SelectAccounts() 
   { 
       var subAccNumber = Request["subAccNumber"];
       var accountName = Request["accountName"];
       var address = Request["address"];
       ...
   }
   ```